# Android notification click

Tags: android

a notification pops up when I get a new task. On click on that notification, it goes to TestExList.java activity.

```
private void createNewTaskNotification(String s, String id) {
    CharSequence title = "TASK";
    CharSequence message = s;

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.checkyes, s,
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, TestExList.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("EmpID", Functions.getLoginEmpID(context));
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            Integer.parseInt(id), notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(id), notification);
}
```

The way it's working is, if i am on another screen, click on notification takes me to TestExList.java.

If i am on the same screen(TestExList.java), it is NOT loading that page aagain. I would like to refresh that page so that I can see my new task on that page.

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: This actually helped me out on figuring a problem with my notification coming from googles push service . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this line

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );
```

this line pops up the activity from activity stack if activity exists, otherwise creates a new instance of the activity, hope this helps.